# Angular2, webpack add external css globally to ng2-admin

Tags: angular, webpack, primeng

I started using ng2-admin and I'm having troubles with primeng. I'm using a datatable and the primeng styles are not applying, I have a plain ugly unformatted table.

I'm following the instructions in here:
http://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/setup

I added these lines in a different project:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/themes/omega/theme.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="YOUR_PATH/font-awesome.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="node_modules/primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css" />
```

It worked in the past but this ng2-admin project uses webpack and I'm not very familiar with it. I read about it and it says to use a css loader in a webpack.config.js I just don't know where and how to add it.

If I add the link directly to the index.html, the files will get a 404 on the files as per the link below.
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/issues/25

Here is the site of ng2-admin
https://github.com/akveo/ng2-admin/tree/master/config
Looking at the files I'm thinking maybe webpack.common.js for both prod and dev?

I would really appreciate some help, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examining the the file config/webpack.common.js I realized that the node_module folder was available to use throughout the application, I just had to create a file somename.loader.ts to add two lines:

```
require('style-loader!primeui/themes/omega/theme.css');
require('style-loader!primeui/primeui-ng-all.min.css');
```

and then include that loader into my component like this:

```
import './somename.loader.ts';
```